# Android time resolution, is there any guarantee?

Tags: android, events, timer, real-time

Is there any guarantee at which precision (by means of a time-'slot') android will answer to timer-events ?

Can I for example rely on an assumption like 'I will definitely get an answer within 100ms' or the like?

EDIT: Since I am currently making an assessment for a very rough preselection of a possible platform, I cannot yet describe a 'specific problem', at least not specific by means ot what **I** would consider precise. But I will try to give an idea of the issue.

For a domotics solution I have several hundred sensors which I want to poll in a configurable timetable. On the hardware-side I will get a USB interface to obtain the values from the outside world. This part is up to somebody else, but the statement is, that I can 'ask' via USB for a particular value and I will get an answer from the domotics installation within 250ms. I can not tell why this takes so long but I have to take this as it is.

Anyway, the application shall be configurable to set the polling time-slices for each single sensor (some values change faster than others). This is very easy on 'blank-metal' platforms but of course very different on OS-controlled solutions. 
Since the sensors do not 'send' values, I have to poll them thus having synchronous processing with the requirement to keep control over the time-grid in which they are polled. I am therefore looking for a reasonable answer to the question "which granularity by means of a time-grid is realistic whith android".

Since I am still assessing where to go (blank µP, raspberry PI, Android, RT-Linux) I simply try to collect information on how much control I can expect to have over this.

Android-development is something new for me, but with the graphical capabilities it provides it is of course a must-assess for me. For that reason I simply do not know how to ask more specifically. If I could, I'd probably be able to answer this question myself.

PS: English is not my native language.

Comment: what do you mean by *timer-events* ? *Can I for example rely on an assumption like  I will definitely get an answer within 100ms*, no you can't. Android isn't Real Time

Answer (score 2):

No. Apps on Android are not running on a [real-time OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) and it's not possible to guarantee any such timing constraints.

Comment: The question is not meant to ask for "real-time" behaviour. It is just: can it happen that I have to wait infinitely, or is there some deadline whithin which I can count on an answer ?

Comment: @emax it depends on the priority of the thread

Comment: Such a deadline would be real-time behaviour. Also I'm not sure what you mean by "answer". Anyway, in practice you don't need to wait an infinite amount of time, there just isn't any guaranteed time.